# Asmx private variable visibility

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I am coding this ASMX web service and I want to use a class variable to manage the response message I send back. I just want to make sure that if multiple client call a web service at the same time the private variable will not be shared amongst the clients creating erratic behaviors. Here is the sample code:

NOTE the variable message is used in all web services of this class I just put one simple method for the sake of presentation.

```
private string message;

[WebMethod]
        public DomainResponseMultiple FindAll(string user, string password, EntityEnum entity)
        {
            DomainResponseMultiple response;
            if (Authenticate(user, password, out message) && HasReadPrivileges(user, out message))
            {
                SelectAllTransaction transaction = new SelectAllTransaction(user, entity);
                response = (DomainResponseMultiple)transaction.Execute();
            }
            else
            {
                response = new DomainResponseMultiple();
                response.ResponseCode = ResponseCode.Error;
                response.Message = message;
            }
            return response;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This variable will be available on the Session scope, as per user, persistant to his session, until it times out according to your configuration

Comment: per session do you mean a service call ? so when a user initiates a call a session is created and when the call completes the session is terminated ?

Comment: When using web services - yes, until the call terminates

Answer (score 1):

As long as it's not static, you shouldn't have a problem.